# Problema al crear un Procedimiento Almacenado en Mysql

Tags: c#, mysql

Les explico mi problema, estoy siguiendo un curso de **C#** y **SQL Server**, pero yo no ocupo el mismo gestor de base de datos si no que **MYSQL** en una parte de un video explica sobre los permisos de usuario. Les muestro esa parte del codigo.

```
DELIMITER
$$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_get_reglas(_id_reglas INT)
BEGIN
DECLARE
    @true BIT -1,
    @false BIT -0
SELECT CASE WHEN
    rgr.id_regla IS NULL THEN @true ELSE @false AND AS Selectd,
    reg.id_regla,
    reg.regla
FROM
    tb_regla reg
LEFT JOIN tb_reglarol rgr ON
    reg.id_regla = rgr.id_regla AND rgr.id_rol = _id_regla
ORDER BY
    reg.id_regla ;
END $$
DELIMITER
;
```

Cuando lo ejecuto me genera este error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Esta son las formas que he intentado

```
 '-DECLARE _verdadero BIT DEFAULT 1;-'
  '-DECLARE _falso BIT DEFAULT 0;-'

 '-DECLARE _verdadero BIT DEFAULT true;-'
 '-DECLARE _falso BIT DEFAULT false;-'

 '-DECLARE _verdadero BIT DEFAULT 1;-'
 '-SET _verdadero = true;-'
 '-DECLARE _falso BIT DEFAULT 0;-'
 '-SET _falso = false;-'

'-DECLARE _verdadero bit(1);-'
'-SET _verdadero = true;-'
'-DECLARE _falso bit(0);-'
'-SET _falso = false-'

'-DECLARE @verdadero BIT DEFAULT 1,-'
'-DECLARE @falso BIT DEFAULT 0,-'
```

Comment: Consejo: No creo que sea conveniente llamarle a una variable `@true` o `@false`, son palabras reservadas, y por que utiliza `-1` y `-0`? Cuando el tipo de dato `BIT` es: Número entero con valor 0 o 1

Comment: Ok, como seria lo mas correcto?

Comment: Cambia el nombre de las variables mencionadas, y coloca 0 y 1 en ves  esos números negativos. No trabajo con MySql pero puede probar: `DECLARE @verdadero BIT DEFAULT 1;`

Comment: Me imagino que también debe funcionar asi: `DECLARE @verdadero   BIT DEFAULT true`

Comment: Mmm, yo trabajo usualmente con Mysql, y no conocía del tipo de datos `bit`, pero por lo que leo en la [documentación](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-type.html), hay todo un tema con la forma de escribirlo, y en ese sentido, te recomiendo regresar al clásico `tinyint`, que es el tipo de datos clásico para albergar el booleano 1 ó 0.

Comment: ya intente de muchas formas y nada aun

Comment: quinqui, como seria la forma mas correcta de poder hacerlo ya que intente de muchas lo pego mas abajo

Comment: Tomando como ejemplo lo que sale en la documentación, específicamente en [Local Variable Scope and Resolution](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/local-variable-scope.html), las variables las declaras con la forma: `DECLARE verdadero TINYINT DEFAULT 1;` o bien `DECLARE verdadero TINYINT; SET verdadero = 1;`. En el caso de "falso", es igual, pero le asignas valor cero.